# Tensorflow python code not running in browser

Tags: python, tensorflow, browser

My tensorflow python code is running fine in terminal when i call it from a php file.

```
<?php
        $python = `python3 Loader.py 2>&1`;
        echo $python;
?>
```

but when i run this php file in browser as

```
localhost:8080/temp.php
```

it is giving error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Loader.py", line 5, in import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

What can be the Solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the python modules imported in Loader.py file?

Comment: import tensorflow as tf